# Spyder "Git Command Line Tools" Issue

Tags: anaconda, ide, spyder

Despite my trials to install the command line developer tools, it keeps providing me with an error message that says "Can't install the software because it is not currently available from the Software Update server". I am on a new mac and am up to date on software.

Does anyone have suggestions on how to install these tools. Another fix would include how I could hide the message pop up from coming up everytime I do anything on the Spyder IDE. I also will include that I installed this IDE through Anaconda.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure it out- on the current Mac OS system you must download XCode in order to fix the issue with command line tools within Spyder.

I'll leave the question and answer here in case it is useful for anyone else.